# Number of Monero block explorers and their unique features

Tags: security, privacy, block-explorer, features

How many Monero block explorers are currently known to exist?

What unique features separate one block explorer from another? What differences do they have in terms of privacy and security vulnerabilities for those who use and rely upon them?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

An incomplete list of explorers with unique features would include [Moneroblocks](http://moneroblocks.info/), [ChainRadar](http://chainradar.com/xmr/blocks), and [The Onion Monero Blockchain Explorer](http://xmrblocksvckbwvx.onion/), of which the clearnet version can be found [here](http://Explore.MoneroWorld.com).

1. Moneroblocks is the most popular explorer (and one of the first if you include its previous .eu domain). It tracks a number of useful [statistics](http://moneroblocks.info/stats), such as mixin usage and transactions per block. It also offers an [API](http://moneroblocks.info/api) and a [rich list](http://moneroblocks.info/richlist), which can be used as a useful introduction of Monero's privacy features to new users.
2. ChainRadar makes it easy to locate the blockchains of numerous CryptoNote coins in one place.
3. The Onion Monero Blockchain Explorer is the newest block explorer and very focused on the security and privacy of its users. It uses no javascript, no web analytics trackers, no images, and is open sourced. There are currently two known hosts of the code, [an onion (Tor) version](http://xmrblocksvckbwvx.onion/) and [a clearnet version](http://Explore.MoneroWorld.com) with plans for an I2P route coming soon.

There are (an unknown number of) other block explorers, but with less unique feature support as those mentioned above.

Note that when looking at the BCN CryptoNote chain on ChainRadar or Minergate, there is strong evidence that transaction volume is artificially created by the same insiders who faked the [BCN inception date](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=740112.0). Because MinerGate seems to be controlled by the same people who control BCN (plus [CoinTelegraph](https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/3g1x60/who_owns_and_runs_cointelegraph_madbitcoins_live/), Changelly, and more) its blockexplorer should never be relied upon as your only source of data.

Answer (score 6):

In addition to MoneroBlocks, ChainRadar and the Onion Monero Blockchain Explorer description from 2quick 4u, there is another new explorer worth mentioning:

[Monero Explorer](https://explorer.xmr.my/) offers:

- [Charts](https://explorer.xmr.my/charts) including difficulty, hash rate, market price and tx volume with plans to [expand data range](https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/4wo67t/new_monero_block_explorer_from_suhz/d68v5y2) options
- Poloniex XMR price and volume data
- Tx logs from recent blocks
- Check Tx feature allowing users to:

  > Check if any of the outputs transaction's belong to the provided address and viewkey.

Comment: This site seems to be down now: https://explorer.xmr.my