# Is there a reason moneroblocks.info is several days behind on the blockchain?

Tags: blockchain

This might not be the right place to ask this and I guess the question isn't even that important. I just became really confused when the height the site showed didn't match the height of my local copy and was wondering if anyone had any insight  into why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears as if the daemon relied upon by that block-explorer is currently down. Only the operator of [moneroblocks](http://moneroblocks.info/) can answer why it is down or when it will be working again.

For now you can rely on one of several [other options](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/538/number-of-monero-block-explorers-and-their-unique-features) such as on [Monero Explorer](https://explorer.xmr.my/).

Comment: Thanks for the links! Since I'm new to Monero I wasn't sure if this was a temporary thing or if the site always was behind for some reason.